# Requirejs + Backbone Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have been starting with Backbone. I used Require to load modul and got this error. Can anyone explain this? In file user.js i have this bug when I try to create Backbone.Model.extend. I used Backbone.js 0.9.10, jQuery v1.9.0, RequireJS 2.1.4, Underscore 1.4.4. Thank you.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Load the script "js/main.js" as our entry point -->
    <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="menu"></div>

    <div id="content"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery:'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore:'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone:'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        templates:'../templates'
    }
});

require(['app'], function (App) {
    console.log('____main.js')
    App.initialize();
    console.log('main.js')
});
```

app.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'router'], function($, _, Backbone, Router) {
    var initialize = function(){
        Router.initialize();
        console.log('app.js');
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

router.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/home/login'
    //'views/room',
//    'views/friend',
//    'views/play',
//    'views/money'
], function ($, _, Backbone, loginView) {
    console.log('router.js');
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            '/home':'showHome',
            '*actions':'defaultAction'
        },
        showHome:function () {
            loginView.render();
        },
        defaultAction:function (actions) {
            console.log('No route:', actions);
        }
    });

    var initialize = function(){
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

login.js(Backbone View)

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/home/users',
    'text!templates/home/login.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, usersCollections, homeLoginTemplate){
    var loginView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('container'),
        render: function(){
            var data = {};
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(homeLoginTemplate);
            this.el.append(compiledTemplate);
        }
    });
    console.log('login.js');
    return new loginView;
});
```

user.js (Backbone Model)

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function (_, Backbone) {
    console.log('user model');
    var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        default:{
            username:"",
            password:""
        }
    });

    return userModel;
});
```

users.js (Backbone Collection)

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'models/user'], function (_, Backbone, userModel) {
    console.log('user collection');
    var usersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:userModel
    });
    return new usersCollection;
});
```

I can't post my picture. But you can see in this link http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/devi.jpg/.

Comment: I'm sure that error gave you a line and stack trace as well?

Comment: var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({...});

Comment: Can you be very clear on what the error is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use that @Ingro said and try to use the default underscore marker when you call to render templates.

for example:

main.js

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery:'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore:'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone:'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        templates:'../templates'
    },

    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
require(['app'], function (App) {
    console.log('____main.js')
    App.initialize();
    console.log('main.js')
});
```

and in anyone file that you use Underscore templates, for example your "login.js" use this:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'collections/home/users',
    'text!templates/home/login.html'
], function(Backbone, usersCollections, homeLoginTemplate){
    var loginView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('container'),
        render: function(){
            var data = {};
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(homeLoginTemplate);
            this.el.append(compiledTemplate);
        }
    });
    console.log('login.js');
    return new loginView;
});
```

jquery and underscore both are used by default in backbone require call.
I hope these help you.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're missing some shim config in your main.js file, read here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

You could try to add:

```
shim: {
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this?. I am getting the same error with exactly the same vendor versions

Comment: Nope, with the shim configuration and the same plugins version it's working fine for me...