# Requirejs + Backbone Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

The error points to the backbone.js:219 library.  The error is thrown in my main.js file in the require(['app'], function.

main.js file:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'scripts',

  paths: {
    app: '../app',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    underscore: 'underscore',
    backbone: 'backbone',
    router: '../router'
  },

  shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function (App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

My app.js file:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router' // Request router.js
], function($, _, Backbone, Router){

  var initialize = function(){
    // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
    Router.initialize();
  };

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

My router.js file:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function ($, _, Backbone) {


  'use strict';

  // Router
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
      "":"list",
      "wines/:id":"wineDetails"
    },

    list:function () {
      // ...
    },

    wineDetails:function (id) {
      // ...
    }
  });
  var initialize =  function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    Backbone.history.start();
  };

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

This question seems to similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617523/requirejs-backbone-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-model-of-undefin), but none of the suggestions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistake in router.js.

1. use the "define" replace "require";
2. return object must contain "initialize" method;

The code like this,

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function ($, _, Backbone) {
  'use strict';

  // Router
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
      "":"list",
      "wines/:id":"wineDetails"
    },

    list:function () {
      // ...
    },

    wineDetails:function (id) {
      // ...
    }
  });
  var initialize =  function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

Comment: These are good corrections, but they did not solve my issue.  Still getting exact same error.

Comment: @ltrainpr, I had edited router.js like that, there isn't error. You could remain only:   
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function ($, _, Backbone) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    initialize: function(){
      Backbone.history.start();
    }
  };
});

Comment: Hi Marlin.  I didn't say the router.js file you updated had an error.  I copied and pasted your code into router.js and it didn't solve my problem.  I'm still getting the TypeError in the console.

Comment: I've updated the router.js file with your recommendation and updated the code in the question.

Comment: @ltrainpr ,I uploaded a sample on the dropbox[backbone-require.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2b9cql19lbdgad/backbone-require.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score -1):

ummmm

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'scripts',

  paths: {
    app: '../app',
    jquery: 'jquery',  //does this actually point to a jquery source file?
    underscore: 'underscore', //does this actually point to a underscore source file?
    backbone: 'backbone', //does this actually point to a backbone source file?
    router: '../router'
  },

  shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function (App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

my first guess is that at some point RequireJS needs to find out where the src/executables are for jQuery, Backbone, Underscore, etc.